# ocaml 4.01.0 → 4.02.1, binary size became larger

Tags: size, ocaml, native-code

On Ubuntu 14.04, 32 bit:

```
➥ cat test.ml
let () = print_endline "hello";

➥ opam switch list | grep " C "
4.01.0  C 4.01.0  Official 4.01.0 release

➥ ocamlopt test.ml 
➥ ls -l a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 158569 Oct.  30 13:29 a.out

➥ opam switch 4.02.0
➥ eval `opam config env`

➥ ocamlopt test.ml 
➥ ls -l a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 171122 Oct.  30 13:30 a.out

➥ opam switch 4.02.1
➥ eval `opam config env`

➥ ocamlopt test.ml 
➥ ls -l a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 171196 Oct.  30 14:08 a.out
```

Executable size became bigger and bigger: 158569 → 171122 → 171196.

In a more complex applications I get an even greater increase in the size of the file.

Any ideas how to fix?

**Update #1**:

Tried `strip`:

```
➥ strip -V | head -n 1
GNU strip (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24

➥ ls -l
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 158569 Oct.  30 15:22 a.4.01.0.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 117368 Oct.  30 15:26 a.4.01.0.out.stripped
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 171122 Oct.  30 15:03 a.4.02.0.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 127580 Oct.  30 15:26 a.4.02.0.out.stripped
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 171196 Oct.  30 15:21 a.4.02.1.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 127612 Oct.  30 15:26 a.4.02.1.out.stripped
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 158569 Oct.  30 15:21 a.out
```

It continues to grow: 117368 → 127580 → 127612

**Update #2**:

Tried option `-compact`, didn't work:

```
➥ opam switch 4.01.0 && eval `opam config env`

➥ ocamlopt test.ml && ls -l a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 158569 Oct.  30 22:02 a.out

➥ ocamlopt -compact test.ml && ls -l a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 158569 Oct.  30 22:03 a.out

➥ opam switch 4.02.1 && eval `opam config env`

➥ ocamlopt test.ml && ls -l a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 171196 Oct.  30 22:05 a.out

➥ ocamlopt -compact test.ml && ls -l a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 171196 Oct.  30 22:05 a.out
```

Tried option `-inline`, didn't work too:

```
➥ opam switch 4.01.0 && eval `opam config env`

➥ ocamlopt -inline 0 test.ml && ls -l a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 158569 Oct.  30 22:07 a.out

➥ ocamlopt -inline 1 test.ml && ls -l a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 158569 Oct.  30 22:07 a.out

➥ opam switch 4.02.1 && eval `opam config env`

➥ ocamlopt -inline 0 test.ml && ls -l a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 171196 Oct.  30 22:08 a.out

➥ ocamlopt -inline 1 test.ml && ls -l a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 shorrty shorrty 171196 Oct.  30 22:09 a.out
```

Comment: interesting, have you tried stripping?

Comment: added information about strip in the post.

Comment: The latter version adds more aggressive inlining, that may explain it.

Comment: you should specify `-inline n` (for native compilation) in each of your experiments.

Comment: there is also a `-compact` option (for native compilation); which will optimize for space rather than speed.

Comment: finally, `-no-alias-deps` may help in 4.02.0 --ensure you are not using side-effects in dependent modules though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code didn't change, but it calls the pervasives module which changed between 4.01 and 4.02.

Notably, the part about formats was changed to use GADT-based formats instead of strings.
This notably made to_string, of_string and concatenation (quite) heavier.

See [this discussion](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=6017) for more details.